# How to know the max `width` in `translateX` animation?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, css-animations

I just want to create something similar to a carousel. (The carousel is just for desktop).

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="image-container">
  <img alt="Siac" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/SIAC_LOGO.svg">
  <img alt="Change" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/CHANGE_LOGO.svg">
  <img alt="HF" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/H_F_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="VDM" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/VDM_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="Reviu" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Reviu_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="Total Capital" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Total_Capital_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="AdelantaT" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/AdelantaT_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="Ayssa" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Ayssa_Logo.svg">
  <img alt="Carga Logística" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Carga_Logistica_Logo.svg">
</div>
</div>
```

```css
/* These padding is here because the real page use them */
.wrapper {
  padding: 0 2.5em;

  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    padding: 0 8em;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    padding: 0 12em;
  }
}

.image-container {
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
      background: transparent;
    }
  }
}

img {
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    height: 100px;
    width: 240px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    animation: moveSlideShow 9s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
    @keyframes moveSlideShow {
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-1440px);
      }
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1280px) {
    @keyframes moveSlideShow {
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-1200px);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you check the transform, it works well for the correct size of the screen, for example if the screen has EXACTLY a width of 768px, the translateX would be -1440px because:

There are 9 images each one with 240px of width

240 * 9 = 2160px

Now, by default, in this size of the screen it should show 3 images, so, If I want to ignore those images and to do the `translateX` exactly to the end, I should do:

2160 - (240 * 3) = 1440px

And that's it, but only for that size, if the screen is a little bit bigger or smaller the animation is not the right one, how can I calculate the right width that `translateX` should use?

This project is using React.js and Styled-components, maybe some javascript can help me, but I don't know what code should I use... :( If you have the solution with React-spring, that would be great because I'm learning it and a solution with this tool would be interesting :)

Comment: Have you tried using percentage values instead of pixel values?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to calculate dynamically like I'm doing with pixels, maybe you know?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `calc` function, like `calc(100% - 20px)`.
For more information, see [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
Note that if you need 100% of the screen width, the `translate` property refers to 100% of its own width. To solve this, try wrapping it in a parent element that will be 100% width, and apply him the `transform: translate` property.

Answer (score 0):

Move the sroll to the upper container and make the inner element `inline-flex` (its width equal to its content) where you can easily consider translation using percentage values. Then you can approximate the width of the container using `vw` unit since it's full width container:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 2.5em;
  overflow: auto;
  --w: calc(100vw - 5em);
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 8em;
    --w: calc(100vw - 16em);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .wrapper {
    margin: 0 12em;
    --w: calc(100vw - 24em);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .image-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    animation: moveSlideShow 9s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
  }
  img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 240px;
  }
  @keyframes moveSlideShow {
    100% {
      transform: translateX(calc(-100% + var(--w)));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img alt="Siac" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/SIAC_LOGO.svg">
    <img alt="Change" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/CHANGE_LOGO.svg">
    <img alt="HF" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/H_F_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="VDM" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/VDM_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="Reviu" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Reviu_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="Total Capital" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Total_Capital_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="AdelantaT" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/AdelantaT_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="Ayssa" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Ayssa_Logo.svg">
    <img alt="Carga Logística" src="https://diey.now.sh/Icons/Clients/Carga_Logistica_Logo.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want, I want to show all the images while they are passing, something like this: https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/ but with these images